# Issue in GetResponseStream() when getting results from Google Image

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, google-api

```
string requestUri = string.Format("http://images.google.com/images?q={0}&ndsp={1}&start={2}&filter={3}&safe={4}",query,RESULTS_PER_QUERY.ToString(),(startPosition+i).ToString(), (filterSimilarResults)?"1":"0",safeSearchStr);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
string resultPage = string.Empty;
using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            resultPage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code and I'm getting the issue below.

responseStream.Length as **'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'**

responseStream.Position as **'responseStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it's way more simple. If the problem still occurs, I would recommend using Fiddler to inspect whether the call was made (and what was returned).